# Python Selenium Click Button Inside Table

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm trying to click on a "VIEW" button from the table shown below in the image from this [site](http://rera.rajasthan.gov.in/ProjectSearch) using Selenium Python.

[image]

I tried using xpath, name and all. How to create a loop for this?

All the entries is to be left empty just click on search button a table is displayed from there "VIEW" button is to be selected

Code:

[image]

Comment: If you present the code, you may get a faster answer.

Comment: are you trying to click on all view buttons in the table...

Comment: @Hietsh Kumar no currently I'm trying to click on first view button row1 col1

Comment: @user13610862 check below and confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below lines , and change the path of driver

```
from selenium import webdriver   
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
opt.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chrome driver\\chromedriver.exe", options=opt)
driver.get("http://rera.rajasthan.gov.in/ProjectSearch")

search_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn_SearchProjectSubmit"]')
# invoke the click() action
search_btn.click()

xpath_first_view =  '//*[@id="OuterProjectGrid"]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]'
# wait for the element to ensure it is available
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,xpath_first_view)))
time.sleep(1) # to ensure click is not very quick
view1_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_first_view).click()
```